# Load an image located in firebase storage

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-storage, android-glide

I have a problem when I try to load an image located in Firebase Storage. In my Firebase project, I have storage an image called "profile.png" inside a folder called "imgProjects".

Searching in StackOverflow, I found some answers that indicates to use Glide for load the image into a "ImageView" element, but isn't working me...

In my activity, I tried:

```
FirebaseStorage storage2 = FirebaseStorage.getInstance("gs://myURLfirebaseProjecy/profile.png"); //I get this URL through firebase console

Glide.with(this)
    .load(storage2)
    .into(imgPerfil);
```

and

```
StorageReference storageRef = storage.getReference();
StorageReference imagesRef = storageRef.child("imgProjects\profile.png");
Glide.with(this)
        .load(imagesRef)
        .into(imgPerfil);
```

I defined "MyAppGlideModule" in a java file class

```
@GlideModule
public class MyAppGlideModule extends AppGlideModule {

    @Override
    public void registerComponents(Context context, Glide glide, Registry registry) {
        // Register FirebaseImageLoader to handle StorageReference
        registry.append(StorageReference.class, InputStream.class,
                new FirebaseImageLoader.Factory());
    }
}
```

and I set the dependency:

```
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-storage:3.3.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.5'
```

When I load the Activity, the ImageView it's empty... I need to use a "gs://" reference or an relative path.

Sorry but... What can I do to solve my issue??

Comment: Have you added `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>` in your manifest file?

Comment: Yes, other Firebase functions working me in the smartphone...

Comment: Please don't use the glide tag to refer to the Android library - use [android-glide] instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can get your image if you know what is the name of you image like this :-

```
StorageReference mImageStorage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();
        StorageReference ref = mImageStorage.child("storage name")
                .child("your image name.jpg");

        ref.getDownloadUrl().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Uri>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Uri> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    Uri downUri = task.getResult();
                    String imageUrl = downUri.toString();
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, imageUrl , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, ""+task.getException(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: I'll try asap and give to you a feedback, thanks for help me!

Comment: @SandeepMalik I'm pretty sure I've seen you post comments like those before - please don't. There's no need for it and it's pretty much just noise. Also, please read [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/88535/332043) before you ask for accepting again. Also, please read "when should I comment" on [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).